# Sharepoint 2010 / Google Chrome / Excel

Tags: excel, browsers

From one of our users:

Now that many of the items seem to work with Sharepoint and Chrome, one of the biggest outstanding issues is that it wants to open the documents in the browser by default.

Opening in the browser does not support simple/common EXCEL functions and results in errors being thrown and me getting hate emails

When using Google Chrome I would like to click on an Excel spreadsheet and have it open with my local  application verses asking to save it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

that behavior is not determined by SharePoint in this instance.  Chrome determines the action based on the MIME type of the content.

IE can utilize the ActiveX control to interface with office and also has default behavior for opening office MIME types in there respective office client. There are addons that allow you to alter Chromes behavior but I have not validated they will allow you to perform this specific action